# Qt 5 Installer Error qmake not parseable

Tags: c++, qt, 64-bit, installation

I have a virtual machine of *windows 8*. I have downloaded the installer for Qt 5 for x64 from [this](https://download.qt.io/development_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.0-beta/) link.

That is the third download. I must say that I have installed this program before on another virtual machine and I didn't get any problem. Now it shows me this error (screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzqtK.png) )

> Error during installation process(qt.56.win64_msvc2015_64):
>   The output of C:\QtThis\QT5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe -query is not parseable.]

Do you have any solution for this? I have tried installing the x86 version but I get errors while compiling my projects: "Qt not installed properly." Know why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Why installing 5.6.0 *beta*?

Comment: I have to use this version of Qt in my college projects. Maybe not all the features we are using are included in earlier versions.

Comment: I mean that it's a **beta**. Can't you install the final 5.6.0 release or even better 5.6.1? Maybe this problem is already fixed.